# How to use #{} without converting array to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have this code block.

```
query  = ['an','array']
@a = params[:action] == 'show' ? "paid" : "paid_students"
variable = "Student.#{@a}(#{query})"
eval(a)
```

But when I run this I am getting "variable" value as

```
Student.paid('anarray')
```

The array is converted to string.How can I avoid this. pls help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#{}` symbol is string interpolation. Its entire purpose is to turn an object into a string and interpolate it into another string. If you want to turn it into a different kind of string, you can certainly do that. For example, if you want to turn it into the string `"[1, 2, 3]"`, you can do `variable = "Student.#{@a}(#{query.inspect})"`.

But a better way to do what you're trying to do would be this:

```
query  = ['an','array']
@a = params[:action] == 'show' ? :paid : :paid_students
Student.send(@a, query)
```

For more information, see the Ruby [`Object#send` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000999).

Answer (score 2):

```
variable = "Student.#{@a}(query)"
```

Doesn't work?

Comment: This also worked in this case :) (n00b here). But he gave some notes also.. I gave Chunk's answer as accepted answer.